# How to show a date comes after a date X excel?

Tags: excel

How do I check if a date in date format is greater than another?

For instance, date in date format in `A1:2014-01-02` and `B1:2014-07-07`

How do show that the date in B1( `2014-07-07`) comes after the date in A1(`2014-01-02`)?

I tried doing this: `if(A1<B1;1;0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
=IF(A1<B1,"Before","After")
```

Or for more rigorous logic

```
=IF(A1<B1,"Before", IF(A1=B1,"Same","After"))
```

Alternatively, to return the later date

```
=IF(A1<B1,B1,A1)
```

Comment: This was a big LOL. So I was onto it however thinking upside down :) Thank you for your quick reply. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hey the problem was using the ; instead of ,

So Change it to

if(A1 < B1,1,0)

Comment: I highly doubt that. Some versions use `;` rather than `,` as the formula separator

Comment: @CallumDS33 May be user3197575 had version issues then.